# Can we make it so questions regarding the Marvel Cinematic Universe are automatically tagged correctly?

Tags: feature-request, tags

There are an awful lot of questions regarding the various MCU properties that are not tagged with the **marvel-cinematic-univ**erse tag.

Is there a way we can automatically tag any questions that contain, for example, the **iron-man-2** tag with the **marvel-cinematic-universe** tag, or at least suggest this tag in addition to the ones they have provided?

Comment: Any implementation would need to be broader than this specific case. Eg a moderator (or a person with sufficiently high rep) should be able to add somewhere, `if tag X, add tag Y`.

Comment: Perhaps we can use tag synonyms.

Comment: There's a very good mechanism. But SE didn't see fit to even respond to the proposal, much less implement it, despite a pretty decent amount of upvotes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so

Comment: @dvk it's not that complicated to implement either.  But would require lots of maintenance work to get tags in the correct order (and I suspect this is why they have not done it)

Comment: @dvk That actually seems a fair bit more complicated than what I was suggesting - I just want a way to filter by -marvel-cinemaitc-universe and not have to check every individual film/TV series tag to ensure I have "caught" all the questions.

Comment: @phantom42 Tag synonyms means there would be no [tag:iron-man-2] for example, only the parent tag would exist.

Comment: @Keen Ah, OK. I thought I remembered them just redirecting to the same source tag.

Comment: FWIW, I try to fix all the missing MCU tags I notice, but I'd love to not have to do so.

Comment: This isn't an easy change to make, so there'd have to be a case for using this on other sites. Consider fleshing this out and creating an MSE proposal for this autotagging idea (separate from the tag hierarchy proposal DVK linked).

Comment: @DVK What Dizzle is proposing is far, _far_ easier than an actual hierarchy, although an informal hierarchy would be the result of it.  The only things I can think of that it'd have to take into account/flesh out for a proposal is chaining (Tag A causes Tag B, which causes Tag C) has to avoid cycles (Tag C cannot be allowed to add Tag A or B by the system), what to do when it would automatically add too many tags, and how it should act during editing/removal of "sub"-tags (maybe it proposes tags but cannot automatically add them?).

Comment: @Izkata Yeah, there are some considerations for looping heirarchies and what not that I haven't considered yet, but I think we have the same idea. I'd consider a text box suggesting the tag, wording something like - "Being as your questions is about `tag1`, would you like to add `tag2` to help it reach a larger audience?"